# Share-post plugin for wordpress not below content but in the comment-container

Tags: wordpress, plugins, share

I'm looking for a wordpress share plugin. The plugins I've used put the share option right under the post content, but I want the share options to appear near mij comment-header "One Response ..."

Is there a descent plugin for that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[SexyBookmarks](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/sexybookmarks/) will provide you with some API functions that you can insert into your WP theme... You will have to create a div with an ID just where you want this share buttons to appear. put SexyBookmarks API call inside that div. then just position that div within style.css. SexyBookmarks also provides you with a few default positionings, but I would realy recommend using API.

ps. - for further WP related questions go to https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/share-post/ is exactly what you would want. It display a variety of customizable sharing button below or above your post.